# Выполнять запрос каждые полтора часа?

Tags: php

Добрый вечер
Как выполнять скрипт каждые полтора часа, именно полтора
1:30,3:00,4:30,5:00 тд
?

есть вариант поставить на крон каждую минуту выполнять скрипт с проверкой времени, но может есть другие варианты?

Comment: 1. поставить крон на каждые полчаса
2. использовать команду at
3. вызывать команду sleep на полтора часа

Answer (score 3):

Правильным решением в рамках крона

```
*/90 * * * * cd /home/user/scripts/ && python3 main.py
```

Answer (score 0):

1.5 часа это 90 минут, вот крон и поставь на каждые 90 минут